# Android Nearby Quick Start examples "Don't Quick Start"

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am attempting to investigate Android Nearby Connections and Messages.

The Google docs suggest starting with the examples in GitHub to be found [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-nearby)

I started with the connections quick start e.g. `com.google.example.connectionsquickstart.MainActivity`

and having updated the gradle build and changed the `Connections.EndpointDiscoveryListener` & `Connections.ConnectionRequestListener` interfaces to classes and installed to two separate devices that are connected to the same WiFi all I can manage to do is get SUCCESS on Advertising and Discovering then nothing else happens.

Until eventually i receive connection Suspended.

Has anyone had these examples working with the current version of google play services? e.g.    `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'`

Comment: Did you use the exact code as what was in the repo? Have you tested if this occurs using a different pair of devices?

Comment: As much as I could I used the exact code, HOWEVER I updated the google play services and target sdk to the most recent versions. I've only tested with a single pair of devices.